# How to split item in a list using python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of items

```
mylist = ['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com', 'example.com\ndistil.example.com\nnext.example.com\nstagepro.example.com\nwww.example.com', 'preferences.example.com']
```

I am trying to remove `\n` from each item. The result should look like this.

```
mylist = ['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com', 'example.com', 'distil.example.com', 'next.example.com', 'stagepro.example.com', 'www.example.com', 'preferences.abc.com']
```

I have tried various methods including `re.split(r'\n')` and `replace()` but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `splitlines()` combined with list comprehension:

```
mylist = [e for elt in mylist for e in elt.splitlines()]
```

Output:

```
['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com', 'example.com', 'distil.example.com', 'next.example.com', 'stagepro.example.com', 'www.example.com', 'preferences.example.com']
```

Comment: Thanks, @Krishna. This solution didn't come to my mind. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split every string in the list in a comprehension and use a nested level to get them back individually into a single list:

```
mylist = ['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com', 'example.com\ndistil.example.com\nnext.example.com\nstagepro.example.com\nwww.example.com', 'preferences.example.com']

mylist = [ s for a in mylist for s in a.split("\n") ]

print(mylist)

['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com', 'example.com',
 'distil.example.com', 'next.example.com', 'stagepro.example.com',
 'www.example.com', 'preferences.example.com']
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Alain. I think we can go for "splitlines()" over "split()" for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate all the strings to form a single string using an `\n` separator and then use `split()` to split the string at `\n`.

```
'\n'.join(mylist).split('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to generate a new list by looping through each part given by splitting the list.

```
mylist = ['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com', 
'example.com\ndistil.example.com\nnext.example.com\nstagepro.example.com\nwww.example.com', 'preferences.example.com']
newlist = []
for item in mylist:
    for web in item.split('\n'):
        newlist.append(web)
```

newlist:
`['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com', 'example.com', 'distil.example.com', 'next.example.com', 'stagepro.example.com', 'www.example.com', 'preferences.example.com']`

Answer (score 0):

I ask two questions:

1. How to convert List to a String?
2. How to convert String to a List?

list1 = list('sales.example.com developer.example.com             example.com\ndistil.example.com\nnext.example.com\nstagepro.example.com\nwww.example.com preferences.example.com')

```
def listToString(s):  
    str1 = "" 
    for ele in s: 
        str1 += ele
    return str1

a = listToString(list2)
b = a.strip("\n")
def Convert(string): 
   li = list(string.split(" ")) 
   return li 

print(Convert(b)) 
['sales.example.com', 'developer.example.com',   'example.comdistil.example.comnext.example.comstagepro.example.comwww.example.com', 'preferences.example.com']
```